# Comparing Data Frames

Tags: r

I have 4 different data frames. I want to create a new data frame using the names mentioned in df1 and the colors associated with these names. df4 does not contain full names, it just has first names. As you can see df4 shows that the first name "Joe" is associated with the color blue. Thus, the full name Joe Carlor is also associated with the color blue. Thank you for your help.

```
df1:

id  age  name        
32  43   Mark Tully  
62  25   Tom Marsi   
34  35   Sal Turner  
44  21   Joe Carlor  


df2:

name        color
Tom Marsi   blue
Jane Tox    blue
Sarah Love  green
Jack Mill   green


df3:

year    name        color  
2004    Mark Tully  green
2011    Ada Lavin   blue
2002    Sarah Love  green
2009    Marcus Toe  green


df4:

first_name   country   color
Joe          USA       blue
Tammy        USA       blue
Lori         USA       green
Sasy         ENG       blue
```

I want to create the below data frame:

```
name        color
Mark Tully  green
Tom Marsi   blue
Joe Carlor  blue
```

Comment: Ideally you can provide code that will reproduce the data so it's easier for people to help you.  You should look up inner joining in R.  That's the main thing you need.  You'll also need string replacement or extract to isolate first names.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to combine dataframe with colors (`df2`, `df3` and `df4`) `separate` their `first_name` and `last_name` and do an `inner_join` with `df1` based on it's `first_name`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(df2, df3) %>%
   separate(name, c("first_name", "last_name"), sep = "\\s+") %>%
   bind_rows(df4) %>%
   inner_join(df1 %>% 
       separate(name, c("first_name", "last_name"), sep = "\\s+", remove = FALSE), 
       by = "first_name") %>%
   select(name, color)

#        name color
#1  Tom Marsi  blue
#2 Mark Tully green
#3 Joe Carlor  blue
```